# Clear session and redirect in same controller method (Play framework with scala)

Tags: scala, session, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to call a method from view, say using anchor tag.. It should clear the session and redirect to default page of my application. I tried

```
Ok("Bye").withNewSession
Redirect(routes.Application.default())
```

But of no use, it is redirecting without clearing the session.. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Redirect(routes.Application.default()).withNewSession`

Comment: Actually i tried this earlier but it didn't work.. But now it worked like a charm.. Thanks a lot serejja...